# Does anyone know of a data description language for products?

Tags: xml, ddl, product

Is there any kind of data description language / XML schema to address describing different kinds of products? I can't find anything of the sort. I'm looking to make something like that, but thought I 'd ask if something was already there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of formats/languages out there for decribing products. But there are mostly very very complex (EDIFACT) or made for specific kinds of products (insurance polices, furniture). You can hardly imagine how much the requirements or different branches or products differ.

If your clients or business partners do not demand a specific format, it is always better to develop your own one which addresses your own needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that the wiki for edifact contains a number of useful pointers.